# Flask-Migrate: Table Already Exists Error

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

From an empty schema on postgres I'm able to create a single table (blog) using flask-migrate using:

1. `python migrate_test.py db init`
2. `python migrate_test.py db migrate`
3. `python migrate_test.py db upgrade`

This creates the table fine.

Then I do the following:

1. Change the table by either adding or deleting a column from the table model in the `migrate_test.py` script.
2. `python migrate_test.py db migrate` which creates the new version in the versions folder.
3. `python migrate_test.py db upgrade`

After this I am expecting the table in the database to be updated to the change. However, I receive the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycogp2.ProgrammingError) relation 'blog' already exists`

The error is correct in that the table 'blog' already exists, what I want to do is update 'blog'. Is the something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**
This is because the line `op.create_table('blog',` is added to the upgrade method of the newly created version. The line is preceded by: `# ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###`.

Checking again and doesn't seem to notice any changes between the first 'blog' model and the updated model, as it trys to create everything again (no add or delete column).

Any ideas why this create table line is being added when the table already exists?

Comment: Are you using the public schema or a different one?

Comment: @Miguel a different schema

Comment: See if [this question](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/176) gives you a solution.

Comment: @Miguel, thank yes I think it tells me I need to do: (include include_schemas=True). Im just not clear on how to do it. Does that go somewhere in the env.py file?

Comment: Yes, this goes in the configure call in the env.py module. See https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/blob/master/flask_migrate/templates/flask/env.py#L73-L76

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. All working well now